# c++ "Expected primary-expression before '.' token" when creating a member function of a class

Tags: c++, class, vector

So I have a class named Zoo which contains a vector called Animals that takes animal objects from the Animal class. The class Zoo also has a member function to add an object animal from the class Animals to the vector.

```
void Zoo::add_member(Animals a)
{ Animals.push_back(a);}
```

However this section of code gives the error primary expression expected before .

Comment: You say "a vector called Animals" and "from the class Animals", are the two `Animals` same thing?

Comment: change vector name to `animals` starting with lower case letter

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Animals` is a name of type and cannot do `push_back()` here.

Change the name of the vector and use `(the new name).push_back(a);`.

Comment: Edit: Thank you, my error was that in my class the vector attribute( Vector<Animal>names  ) I read the name of the vector as Animal instead of names.

Comment: I guess no if it is used as class member. http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/FDehdIS3cKtC7nAT

Comment: why downvote this post ?? whats wrong with the answer ?